# How to prevent access to the web site from different ip with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, session, webforms

I would like to create a layer of security. For example:

```
User = John (Signed in) has a Session["ipadress"]
Hacker = Unknown (using same session_id) has a same Session["ipadress"] or new one? i need an information..
```

Well, i would like to check an ip adress and if it's different from registered and logged in user than redirect to sessioninactive.aspx page.

Is it possible to do in global.asax?

Comment: `if it's different for registered and logged in user`, what happens if the registered user's IP changes?

Comment: normally, user is not changing ip adress during shopping, using application or playing a game online. Somehow if IP Address changes that we can end the session for user's security and user will need to sign in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following methods in Global.asax

Save the IP to session on Session_Start:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
  string userIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
  Session["ipadress"] = userIp;
}
```

On each request, see if the request IP is same as saved in session:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState()
{
  string userIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

  if (Session["ipadress"] != null)
  {
    string originalUserIp = Session["ipadress"].ToString();
    if (originalUserIp != userIp)
    {
      Response.Redirect("sessioninactive.aspx");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i can get an ip address with this code but thing is i am planning to check an ip adress on Session_Start if it's possible. let's imagine we know user is in the system and have a active session. And somehow unknown request comes from another ip. We can think about someone knows user name and password for this user. Or there would be  a stolen session_id via cookie

Comment: Try the updated solution, it should solve the problem.

Comment: thank you rashid. i was set the ip address in session_start but i didn't imagine about Application_AcquireRequestState. I hope your solution will help to the others.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job inside Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

        //TODO: handle correct list
        List<string> validIps = new List<string> { "::1" };

        if (!validIps.Contains(ip))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "Forbidden";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that at the place where I check the user. For example on the login page.
You can simply do something like that:

```
string sUserHostaddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Then you can compare your Seesion["ipaddress"] (you can populate that session variable the same way) with sUserHostAddress.

Not sure what you mean with imitating session_id? I wouldn't rely on cookies to manage authenticated state. I think the important aspect is that your login is secure. Password encrypted. I would always check a session cookie against the actual used SessionID and if they don't match I get suspicious (can write code to do something about that).

You might run into a problem if the user uses a proxy which changes the IP address during a sesion. Saw something like that in my log files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am thinking about asp.net cookie has ASP.NET_Session_id. Someone can stole and try to use it or if some one knows targeted user's user name and password. Trying to get an ip address on session_start. So, if  ip address changes can not login the system. Because we have active session on the system right? Just need a little bit trick for it.

Comment: You can control the lifetime of ASP.NET_Session_id. I usually use the default settings in the web.config which is 20 min. Non shopping sites I do longer. After that the session expires. New login required. I also set the SessionID in a cookie (not the ASP.Net one an additional one). Then I can read that cookie too and compare with the active SessionID. You can give the cookie any name and you can encrypt it too. It's hard to guess what it might mean. Use HttpOnly = true when creating a cookie. Adds another layer of security. Glad that you gave me a vote for my initial answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks i already use HttpOnly=true for default asp.net cookie. Just thinking about deny login from different IP address at the same time and man in the middle things right now. I will evaluate your other suggestion.

Comment: I guess you have set requireSSL="true" in the web.config too. This will encryot the cookie. Interesting thought about multiple logins at the same time. Need to think about that too now.